# How can I solve this trigonometry question?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

$ABC$ is a triangle

$m( A \widehat BC) = m( A \widehat CB) + 90^\circ$

$3 \lvert AC \rvert = 7 \lvert AB \rvert$

area of the $ABC$ triangle is $4{,}2$ cm$^2$

$\lvert BC \rvert =$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sine rule says :$${BC\over \sin\angle A}={AB\over \sin\angle C}={AC\over \sin\angle B}={AC\over \cos\angle C}\implies \tan\angle C=3/7$$$$\implies \sin \angle C=3/\sqrt{58}$$
Now since you know $\angle C$, you know$\angle B \ \&\ \angle A$

Hence you get $BC$in terms of $AB$. Now apply formula$$Area=4.2=0.5\times BC\times AC\sin\angle C$$ you will get value of $AB$ and hence $BC$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The area of a triangle could be expressed in terms of product of two sides and the sine of the angle in between.
http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/algtrig/att13/areatriglesson.htm

So the angle $A$ can be found.
And then that with the given angle equation, reveal all angles.
You can then recover the length $|BC|$ by applying the area formula once more.